# How to Password Protect a Web Page in IIS Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am new to **IIS server** and configuration. I have a task to **protect** few **webpages** on IIS server using a **password** so that only certain users can access. The password-protected webpage will prompt the user for a password which then will be compared with the password hash stored in the website folder or web config.

The issue is that I don't know how to store a protected data like passwords in IIS server that I can access on the site. My question is how or where can I store the password hash within the website project and how I can access it from the webpage? Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/basicauthentication

Comment: This is far too broad of a question for SO. Anything that needs an entire blog post to answer is asking too much. "how to create a password protected website that allows users to get password and maybe reset them etc" is much bigger than "how do I get the last non null element of an int? array using LINQ"

Comment: @CaiusJard, I understand. I only need to know how I can store the password hash either in web.config or some other place within the website folder, and how I can access it from the webpage.

Comment: @CaiusJard, I improved my explanation and hopefully narrowed the scope of the question.

Comment: For your specific requirements, you have to develop your own web app (forms authentication with your own hash based provider) to authenticate. There is no built-in support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a service hosting platform, IIS's main function is to run applications for a long time. Essentially it is a server and not a database.

Data should not be stored in the server, especially the password to protect the application page should be stored in the database.

Passwords are usually very important data. For users, it is just a simple combination of numbers and letters. But in the server and database, it should not be the obvious plaintext but the encrypted code. The application encrypts the password and stores it from the server to the database. This is the correct process of storing the password.

Learn [authentication and authorization filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters). This should be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Probably terrible but you could store the hash as an appsetting in the web.config file?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you give me an example of how to store the hash in the appsetting in the web.config file. Also, how can I access it on my web pages?